# How to position an icon in the middle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm using pyqt5 to create a video play/pause button. I want to display a shortcut key next to an icon in the center of the button. When only an icon is inserted, the icon is located in the center. However, if a button has a shortcut key, button becomes that It's the form I don't want.
How to position an icon in the middle??

```
        self.btn_pp = QPushButton(self)  # Main tab / video play/pause button
        self.btn_pp.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)  # 1211 창 크기 변경 시 버튼 크기 자동 조절
        self.btn_pp.setCheckable(True)
        self.btn_pp.setChecked(False)
        self.btn_pp.setEnabled(False)
        self.btn_pp.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(./icon/background.jpg); ")
```

**only icon**

```
        icon_pp = QIcon()
        icon_pp.addPixmap(QPixmap("./icon/pause.png"), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.On)
        icon_pp.addPixmap(QPixmap("./icon/play.png"), QIcon.Active, QIcon.Off)
        icon_pp.addPixmap(QPixmap("./icon/pause.png"), QIcon.Active, QIcon.On)
        self.btn_pp.setIcon(icon_pp)
        self.btn_pp.clicked.connect(self.pp)
```

result:
[image]

**icon + string(shortcut key)**

```
        icon_pp = QIcon()
        icon_pp.addPixmap(QPixmap("./icon/pause.png"), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.On)
        icon_pp.addPixmap(QPixmap("./icon/play.png"), QIcon.Active, QIcon.Off)
        icon_pp.addPixmap(QPixmap("./icon/pause.png"), QIcon.Active, QIcon.On)
        self.btn_pp.setIcon(icon_pp)
        self.btn_pp.setText("    (p)")
        self.btn_pp.clicked.connect(self.pp)
```

result:
[image: ![enter image description here]

i want:[image]

Comment: Why are you asking again the same question you just [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72249409/how-to-position-an-icon-in-the-middle)?

Comment: @musicamante At the time of writing that question, I was in a situation where I had to turn it off urgently. So I thought I didn't write the right question.
I wrote the question in a hurry, so I couldn't write exactly what I wanted. With that in mind, I re-uploaded it after a few corrections. beacuse I want to solve the above problem. If I did something wrong, I want to apologize.

Comment: Then I have 2 suggestions. 1. *never* rush a question; you may think "I'm in a hurry and want to have an answer as soon as possible", but chance is that you'll probably make a question with missing details, typos, insufficient data or code, with the result that people would point out those issues and you'll be still waiting for an answer after fixing them; take your time, creating a *good* question requires *a lot* of that (sometimes even hours), but is also often rewarded with upvotes and thus more visibility, so it's more likely that people would notice and answer it, instead of ignoring it.

Comment: 2. You can (and should) always [edit] a question whenever you want to add details or fix some aspects; this is especially important whenever there are *comments* that would otherwise become lost, and those comments might be useful to other readers too (for instance, they will not ask/write the same observations somebody else already had). Editing is always preferable, and a question should be *replaced" with a new one only in rare occasions (for instance, you got too many down votes). Also, as a new user, there's a limit on how many question you can ask in a certain period.

Comment: @musicamante Thanks for the advice. I'll pay attention to comments and other explanations so I can focus on writing good questions.